# How do I get the dimensions of QTMovie

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting

I'm trying to get a QTMovie's height and width, but can't get it right.

Here's the code (using ARC):

```
// get the movie's dimensions
NSSize *sourceSize = (__bridge NSSize *)([[movie movieAttributes] valueForKey:@"QTMovieNaturalSizeAttribute"]);

NSLog(@"%@", sourceSize);
// the output seems OK:
// NSSize: {1920, 1040}

NSLog(@"%f x %f", sourceSize->width, sourceSize->height);
// here's the output:
// 0.000000 x 0.000000
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is it just me, or `NSSize` isn't really an Objective-C class?

Comment: It's a struct: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html

Comment: That's what I'm saying... Ah wait, got the solution! You know `valueForKey:` doesn't return scalars and raw structs? It returns Objective-C objects. Read its documentation - if the value for a key is a scalar or a struct, then it's wrapped in an `NSValue` (or in an `NSNumber` in the case of numbers). So, `sourceSize->width` and `sourceSize->height` don't point to valid `float`s, but to some arbitrary memory within an `NSValue` object.

Comment: (I'm also curious why you assumed this would work at all? Key-value coding never worked like this, and the documentation even mentions it **explicitly**...)

Comment: Just a noob trying to get stuff to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to H2CO3's comments I got this to work. This is where I went wrong:

`[movie movieAttributes]` returns an NSDictionary and `valueForKey` is KVC which does not return non-object values but instead [wraps them](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/DataTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002171-184580-BCIEDECF).

So `NSSize sourceSize = [[[movie movieAttributes] valueForKey:@"QTMovieNaturalSizeAttribute"] sizeValue]` would be the correct way to retrieve the `NSSize` struct.

Also - as H2CO3's comment suggests - this was a stupid mistake. Getting started is hard :-)